# Red5 1.0.0 rc2 flv play not working

Tags: red5

I have published well my record files on red5 server but it hangs during play streams even

default streams .

It only shows meta info but not playing anything

version is red5 1.0.0 rc2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry from this snippet of information it is not likely that anybody could answer this.
You might simply use thee demo applications and modify those to fit your needs or prepare sample code and output.

Comment: Maybe this issue solves your problem too? https://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/detail?id=272